# Release configuration for asp.net forms website

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, webforms

In .net web applications we have at least two build configurations which allows us to build for debug and build for release.

There is only debug build configuration in website project. I have read the Microsoft explanation of website are not complied, so they do not need a release configuration.

But still there are some specific configurations to be added when deploying to the production,

eg:- We have to set `debug` to false under `compilation`.

Is there a way to pre configure build/publish. So we do not need any manual config change when deploying for production?

Answer (score 0):

No other way to change it.

Generally, we sets two environments for application, one is for debugging, one is for production.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, with your pattern how the source control work with that? do you have two separate branches? if so how they sync each other?

in my case there is one branch for development, and in that branch I used to have these configurations set for development. So, each time when I deploying for the production I have to change these configs manually.

Comment: Hi，there are lots of source code control tools and continues integration tools(CruiseControl.Net，Jenkins). Meanwhile, we rules that do not push local configuration to cloud in the beginning.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. But my questions is, in usual C#.NET application it is easy to run the release build and package it and send it for deployment. Is there any such mechanism for aps.net web forms too?